# Scala reduce duplicate code from inheritance

Tags: scala, inheritance

```
class CharacterFilter extends Filter[Character] {
    def _name(n: String) = { data = data.filter(c => c.name == n) }
}
class NPCFilter extends CharacterFilter {
    def name(n: String) = { _name(n); this }
}
class PlayerFilter extends CharacterFilter {
    def name(n: String) = { _name(n); this }
}
```

I'm building some classes that filter through data. `NPCFilter` and `PlayerFilter` should share methods from `CharacterFilter`. However, I want each filter to return themselves at the end so that I can chain functions like this:
`.name("John").age(18).race(WHITE)`

At first I tried this, but it doesn't give the result I want, because I am left with a `CharacterFilter` after calling `name` instead of a `NPCFilter` or `PlayerFilter` as desired.

```
class CharacterFilter extends Filter[Character] {
    def name(n: String) = { data = data.filter(c => c.name == n); this }
}
class NPCFilter extends CharacterFilter {
}
class PlayerFilter extends CharacterFilter {
}
```

So my first example works exactly how I want it to, but it feels repetitive (especially once I add more functions). Is there a way to make it more concise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this particular case where you return `this`, there is a direct support :

```
def f(....) : this.type =  ....
```

Writing that, `this` is the only valid return value, and the compiler will type it just as it typed the target of the call to `f`.

Short of that particular case, if your return type is somewhat tied to the type of the target, but not necessarily `this`, you need a type member, or a generic, such as

```
abstract class A[T <: A[T]] {self: T =>
   def f(....): T
}

class B extends A[B] { ... }
```

Comment: The first snippet works great! I've never seen this `T <: A[T]` syntax before. What is it called so I can do some research on it?

Comment: The square brackets means type parameter. So A is a generic class, with type parameter T. The <: is a sub typing constraint, (upper bound), meaning that T must be a subtype of A[T]. For your use case, this.type is the way to go. The type parameter solution is for more complex cases.